# How manage my json content with Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I want to recover  the contents of my json but i can't. and the console  "say Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'longitude' of undefined" I'm very new with this method. Thank you if you can help me.

```
var recuptable = [];

     $(document).ready(function(){
     $.ajax({
         url: 'http://******',
         type: 'get',
         dataType: 'JSON',
         success: function(response){         

           recuptable.push(response);
         }

     });

 });

 console.log(recuptable[1].longitude);
```

Comment: Please see [How do I return the response from an aynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/438992), which this duplicates.

Comment: @DaveNewton Why not mark it as such? :)

Comment: ok Thank you Dave I check 

Comment: @TylerRoper Because the shortcut fails on this machine for an as-yet unknown reason, and I was off-line before I realized it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is async, when you console log your variable it is still empty. Instead, move the console.log inside the success function.

```
var recuptable = [];

     $(document).ready(function(){
     $.ajax({
         url: 'http://******',
         type: 'get',
         dataType: 'JSON',
         success: function(response){         
           console.log(response.longitude);
           recuptable.push(response);
         }

     });

 });
```

Also, I suggest you read a little bit about callbacks and/or about promises so that you are able to work with async code more easily.

Comment: Ok Thank you I understand.